# How to use Alamofire ? (design patterns)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, afnetworking, alamofire

With Objective-C and AFNetworking, I used to extend the `AFHTTPSessionManager` and created a singleton shared client to handle all requests.

However with `Swift 2.0` and `Alamofire 3.4` , if I'm going to follow a similar approach, which classes should I extend? (`AFHTTPSessionManager` equivalent?) 
Or is this even necessary with `Alamofire`? because it appears all the requests are already being handle by a shared manager in `Alamofire`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [manager section](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manager) you have several options. If you want to handle simple requests, you can just use the default manager via `Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")` you can also modify session configuration:

```
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
defaultHeaders["DNT"] = "1 (Do Not Track Enabled)"

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

If you have more complex needs you should consider subclassing. Hope this short answer helps :)